# Reading from Firebase in app creation with FlutterFlow

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I'm currently creating an app using FlutterFlow and Firebase. If I add a tab bar to the page and perform a collection query for each tab, which scenario would it be, ➀ or ➁?

When transitioning to the page, perform queries for all tabs. Reads for all queries will be executed.
When transitioning to the page, reads are executed for each individual tab.

Furthermore, I'm also curious about the following: In the case of ➀ or ➁, will the documents be read again every time I switch tabs?

I want to ask a question